# How to build a meta-driven application in emberJS

Tags: ember.js, metadata, sugarcrm

***Note***: *The English used in this article (along with the terms) may be a bit **"out of order"** since my native language is not English. Rest assured I have tried my best to make it as readable as possible, and if I have missed anything please do comment before downvoting so I may update the question accordingly (I'm still new to this)*

So I've searched most of the internet for a solution to this, to find a tutorial that would guide me on the metadata driven approach for building an application on EmberJS. The documentation on Ember doesn't explain anything about the approach, just a function definition of extractMeta [here](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.4/classes/DS.JSONSerializer/methods), and a basic overview of how to handle metadata [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/handling-metadata/).

What I want to achieve is to build a portal, with `Sugar` as the back-end for the application. The application will use `REST` API for making calls to extract the data as well as the `metadata` of the application. We want to make the application generic, so that no matter what module is called, the metadata is extracted to determine the fields required in the model, a filtered portion of the data needed from the call is populated into the model accordingly and the is displayed in a generic template, that will be global and used throughout the application.

The `metadata` includes various items such as `buttons`, `panels`, `attributes`(each with multiple layers of data within) etc, each may be used once or multiple times within the call or not at all. For example, for displaying the application would require the `attributes` for display within the table, as well as `buttons` for adding, deleting updating etc. Upon click the `panel` may be required for say, adding a particular record, which itself may contain various fields.

[image: list]
As an example, is the default `Sugar` instance that shows the **leads** in the data, notice how it contains various components.

[image: add data]
Here, another example, of the panel that appears when I click the **create** button in the leads list, notice the fields that appear within the panel

Please Note that I do understand how to make the `REST` API calls for the `data` as well as the `metadata`. But how to turn that into a generic **meta driven** application is what I am struggling with. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please read [ask] and provide the context, and/or post code samples of a [mcve] of what you have done, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: Thankyou for the advice, I'll keep these in check from now. I understand how this does seem very vague and not very well written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you're looking for some kind of generic UI builder based off of returned data from a REST endpoint. Ember provides the `component` helper.

> The `{{component}}` helper can be used to defer the selection of a
>   component to run time. The `{{my-component}}` syntax always renders the
>   same component, while using the `{{component}}` helper allows choosing a
>   component to render on the fly. This is useful in cases where you want
>   to interact with different external libraries depending on the data.
>   Using the `{{component}}` helper would allow you to keep different logic
>   well separated.

```
{{#each model as |post|}}
  {{!-- either foo-component or bar-component --}}
  {{component post.componentName post=post}}
{{/each}}
```

Read [here](https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/05/13/component-helper) for a more thorough explanation.

What you essentially need to do is build a bunch of different components for each of the possible attributes from the `metadata`. Your models will contain what components they should render and you'll use the `component` helper to dynamically render the correct elements.

If you're using a table based approach, have a look at [ember light table](https://offirgolan.github.io/ember-light-table/#/). They leverage this approach heavily with how they build the columns for their tables and support custom components:

```
columns: computed(function() {
    return [{
      label: 'Avatar',
      valuePath: 'avatar',
      width: '60px',
      sortable: false,
      cellComponent: 'user-avatar'
    }, {
      label: 'First Name',
      valuePath: 'firstName',
      width: '150px'
    }];
  })
```

As you see here, the columns are rendered generically and they use the `cellComponent` property to determine which component type to render.

Comment: Another addon you may want to consider for generating dynamic tables is [`ember-contextual-table`](https://github.com/tubitak-bilgem-yte/ember-contextual-table#readme). While ember-light-table takes a configuration based approach, ember-contextual-table is using a template based one, which feels more the ember way IMO.

Comment: Thanks @sunrize920, a very vivid explanation of exactly what I wanted to know. I really didn't bring up `components` into the picture, but now I do understand how to go about the process thanks to your detailed answer. :)

Comment: @MuhammadHamza upvotes are the best way to show that you like an answer ;)

Comment: @jelhan I think you're right, a template based approach would fit in with the ember architecture better than configuration based approach, although might have to study both first to determine which one works better for me. Thanks!

Comment: @sunrize920 I did :), my connection hung up on me, had to refresh, apologies :/

Comment: @jelhan but isn't the very idea of the question here a configuration based approach to a table? IMO ember light table is a much better fit for this specific need, even though a template based approach might be more "the ember way". I actually rolled my own configuration based approach to tables in ember 3 years ago that were dynamically built from backend params and the approach worked very well.